# Reverting the Load statement of Impala?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

I have created a table on Impala and loaded data into table.

Now the data from HDFS is moved to Impala data directory how can i Find this data on HDFS??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `impala-shell` in a server where you have installed impala and type the command:

```
   DESCRIBE FORMATTED table_name;
```

It will show the location of the table in `hdfs`.

Comment: thanks form this command i can find the location.Here the data is stored in /user/hive/warehouse/<table_name> instead of /user/impala/ on HDFS that is the one point to notice.